# What is the meaning of the following expression in scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to understand a source code.. (basically a regex parser).. But I am not able to understand the following expression:

```
def quotes = “‘“ ~> "[^']+".r <~ "'"
```

So I understand that [^'] means that find everything except the single quote? right?? but what is the double quotes next to it.. and what are those squigly arrows with single quote inside double quotes??

Comment: can u share other part of code

Comment: shared.. the code.. see edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"'" ~> "[^']+".r <~ "'"` matches a single quote block :

starting with a single-quote (`"'"`)  + containing more than one non-single-quote character (`"[^']+".r`) + ending with a single quote (`"'"`).

Comment: but what are those squigly arrows?? "~>"

Comment: those are auxiliary operators `~>` and `<~` which discard the result of one of the operand, typically the constant parts in the rule which carries no useful data.

Comment: so that you only get the values inside the quote, not including the quote

Comment: @aelor A very naive question... Is there a java or python or another equivalent regex in scala which doesnt uses those squigly arrows?

Comment: @Fraz not very sure if you can use a regex like `(?<=")[^']+(?=")` in scala. lookarounds can be helpful in this case

Comment: this is not a simple regex match, that's a piece of some grammar defined with scala parser combinators library